# Simplifying Radicals in Numerator and Denominator

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I am new to Mathematica. So I am sorry if the question seems elementary.

I wanted to simplify an expression but it seems that some radicals ($\sqrt{u}$ and $\sqrt{u-1}$) in numerator or denominator do not cancel. What should I do?

```
f = Sqrt[u (-1 + u^2) - (-1 + u^2)^2] ((u (-1 + 2 u))/(
2 Sqrt[-u + u^2]) + Sqrt[-u + u^2])

FullSimplify[f]
```

and the result is

[image]

My final goal is to get

$$f = {1 \over 2}\sqrt { - u\left( {u + 1} \right)\left( {{u^2} - u - 1} \right)} \left( {4u - 3} \right)$$

Comment: Is `u` positive?  If so, is it greater than 1?  This matters in the cancellations.

Comment: Please help us to help you. Here is consider helpful to include the code in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) so we can *copy and paste* your code.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: Yeah, I think this is the point! In fact, $u \ge 1$. Can you elaborate please. :)

Comment: @rhermans: Is there any problem with putting pictures? I am new mathematica but not to SE! :)

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it, as @rhermans said. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2: OK. Thanks for the guide. I will do so.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about `FullSimplify`, esp. the parts that explain this summary, "`FullSimplify[expr,assum]` does simplification using assumptions."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are seeking?

```
FullSimplify[f, u > 1]
(* 1/2 u (-3 + 4 u) Sqrt[2 + 1/u - u^2] *)
```

**Response to edit in question**

The `LeafCount` of this result is

```
LeafCount[%]
(* 24 *)
```

On the other hand, the `LeafCount` of the outcome desired by the OP is

```
g = 1/2  (-3 + 4 u) Sqrt[-u (u + 1) (u^2 - u - 1)]
LeafCount[%]
(* 27 *)
```

Note also that

```
FullSimplify[g, u > 1]
(* 1/2 (-3 + 4 u) Sqrt[u + 2 u^2 - u^4] *)
LeafCount[%]
(* 25 *)
```

which may be a more desirable result, if `1/u` is not wanted in my first answer.  I should add that most any transformation of `f` can be obtained with `FullSimplify`, but often not easily.

Comment: Can you kindly see the updated question. I think it is not really fully simplified yet! $\sqrt{u}$ is not cancelled!

Comment: @@bbgodfrey, What is `FullSimplify` doing with these assumptions?  The answer it comes out with does not depend on the assumptions, and seems to be true for any complex value of `u`:  `f2 = FullSimplify[f, u > 1]; 
Equal @@ {f, f2} /. u -> RandomComplex[{-10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}]`

Comment: @H.R.  The issue is that your desired "simplified" result is less simple than mine as assessed by `LeafCount`.

Comment: It's interesting that your form can be found by making the unnecessary assumption that `u>1` (does that imply that `Element[u,Reals]`?), the OP's desired form is only true when `u>1`.

Comment: @JasonB  The two expressions seem to be equal in many but not all cases.  Consider `Equal @@ {f, f2} /. u -> .5 + .3 I`, which is `True`.  However, `Equal @@ {f, f2} /. u -> .5 - .3 I` is `False`.  Interesting question, nonetheless.